# Android handle onStop and onDestroy user behavor

Tags: android, authentication, ondestroy

I have a login user flow, user logins with Google+ or Facebook. Then in the next activity he choose gender and a nick name if its his first time in the app (Shared Preferences). When user press 'Go' button, he triggers the upload function:

```
public void uploadUserData() {
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (firebaseUser != null) {

            final String userUid = firebaseUser.getUid();
            final String username = editUsername.getText().toString().trim();
            final String user_class = String.valueOf(class_spinner.getSelectedItem());
            final String user_gender = String.valueOf(gender_spinner.getSelectedItem());
            FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            DatabaseReference users = database.getReference("Users");
            users.child(userUid).child("userName").setValue(username);
```

After this, user dont see again this activity and his account has all the informations i need.

My problem is how to prevent user from exit app (onDestroy) without have press enter button. If he do it, i dont have the nickname and the next time he opens the app the activity he faces need the username. (Throws null exception obviously).

The flow:
Welcome activity

```
if (!prefManager.isFirstTimeLaunch()) {
            launchHomeScreen();
            finish();
        }
private void launchHomeScreen() {
        startActivity(new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
```

In main activity:

```
@Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                    FirebaseUserMetadata metadata = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getMetadata();
                    if (metadata.getCreationTimestamp() == metadata.getLastSignInTimestamp()) {
                        // The user is new, show them a fancy intro screen!
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewUserActivity.class));

                    } else {

                        if (prefManager.isFirstTimeLaunch()) {
                            // This is an existing user, show them a welcome back screen.
                            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewUserActivity.class));
                        }
                        else{
                            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserProfile.class));
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
        };
```

And in NewUserActivity:

```
btnEnterDungeons.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(editUsername.getText().toString().trim())) {
                    uploadUserData();
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setClass(NewUserActivity.this, GameChooseActivity.class);
                    prefManager.setFirstTimeLaunch(false);
                    finishAffinity();
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
```

So if user destroy the NewUserActivity with no pressing the btnEnterDungeons the prefManager remains. But when the cycle starts again as use is already logged in with Google+ or Facebook... goes to NewUserActivity and throw exception for UserProfile.

End the error occurs in line 164 in UserProfile. That means it shows NewUserActivity but loads UserProfile too.

```
//Method to get data from Firebase user and show them in profile
    private void getData() {
        final Context mContext = UserProfile.this;
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        String userid = user.getUid();
        final long joinedDate = user.getMetadata().getCreationTimestamp();
        final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm");
        final Date resultdate = new Date(joinedDate);
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        reference.child(userid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                userName.setText(user.getUserName());
                userClass.setText(user.getUser_class());
                imageURL = user.getAvatar();
                Picasso.with(mContext).load(imageURL).into(userAvatar);
                dateofJoin.setText((sdf.format(resultdate)));
                PvPWins.setText(String.valueOf(user.getPvP_Wins()));
                PvPScore.setText(String.valueOf(user.getPvP_scores()));
                userScore.setText(String.valueOf(totalScore));
                userGender.setText(user.getUser_gender());


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: Any reason to not consider using another `Shared Preference` to check if the process is completed ? if not completed then show it again when user comes back otherwise if the user clicks on "GO" then don't show the process.

Comment: Hmmm the main reason of this is that i havent think it i guess...:) I thing it will work. Even if it doesnt work, its a must had think solution

Comment: Actually i cant understand how this is possible. make something like  
        loginManager = new LoginManager(this);
        if (!LoginfManager.isCompleted()) {
            launchHomeScreen();
            finish();
        }else{????} How to show the same activity again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Shared Preferences` to check if the user has completed the "Registration" task or not.

So typically the process will look as follow:

1. In your Launcher activity, might be your "SplashScreen" or the "Login" activity, you check the `Shared Preferences` and see if the value of `processCompleted` is true, by default the value is false
2. If value is true , it means the user has already completed the process so you can launch the "Home" intent directly
3. If the value is false, it means the user didn't complete the process, so you show the "Login" intent
4. When the user clicks on "GO" it means he finished the process so you update the value of `processCompleted` in `Shared Preference` with true.
5. Next time the user opens the app the `processCompleted` will be true and you will be sure that he actually gave all informations you need.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Almost there. Actually the part you suggested works!. I set the firstLaunch false only when the GO button pressed. If user exit, starts again in splash screen as it should, goes to the activity for enter the username, but for some reason get null exception for the next activity that should load IF its not firsttime lounch. Like both activities loading...

Comment: @HealthydevDevelopments  if you update the question with your code, it will be easier to help